# Hide view while push to tabBar - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I have a view controller like below.

[image]

This view is attached with a tabBarController. The tabBarController has 5 viewControllers and I have to present the 5th viewController of tabBar from another page. So I used the below codes for present that viewController

```
@IBAction func onClickUserProfile(_ sender: Any) {
        let navVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileVC")as! ProfileVC
        navVc.userId = Int(self.userId)
        navVc.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        navVc.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nxtVc, animated: true)
    }
```

But after execute the code it resulting the view controller as the below image. 
The view undergoes the tabBar. Anyone help me to push to a tabBar view.

[image]

Comment: try to set automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false, in ProfileVC(viewDidLoad)

Comment: Nothing happens.The view return the same result

Comment: Why don't you use the present function to present your view controller?

Comment: While using present it hides the tabBar and navigationBar

Comment: What is the bottom constraint of the "Sell Your Staff" button ?

Comment: You can use your tabBar to access the 5th VC and switch your VC that way, it should be better than create new instance to push, the issue should because the constraint that connect to the button

Comment: @Ahmet set the bottom constraint to super view

Comment: @Tj3n How to access the tabBar and switch to 5th VC can you please explain it with code

Comment: @AngelFSyrus check the answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the selected `UIViewController` from `UITabBarController`  something like this should work .

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![1]
```

where `tabBarController?.viewControllers` returns the array of current `ViewControllers` embedded in the `UITabBarController` .

Your code should be something like this.

```
@IBAction func onClickUserProfile(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc =  self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![1] as! ProfileVC // use your index
        vc.userId = Int(self.userId)
        self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController = vc
    }
```

> **Note**: Don't create an instance of the `UIViewController` as `.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` use the already existed
>   ones in the array `tabBarController?.viewControllers`, creating new
>   instance will be treated as new one and gives the problem you have up
>   there .